# Incorrect output for tic-tac-toe game

Tags: python, python-3.x, tic-tac-toe

I am having trouble correcting the output for this code:

```
    print('--------')
    print('|'+board[7]+ '|' +board[8] +'|' +board[9]+'|')
    print('--------')
    print('|' +board[4]+ '|'+board[5]+'|' +board[6]+'|')
    print('--------')
    print('|' +board[1]+ '|'+board[2]+'|' +board[3]+'|')
    print('--------')

real_board=['#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#','#']
```

```
def xchecker_tool(board, mark):
    vertical=print(f'congratulations player {mark}! you have won by lining up vertically on the board!')  
    horizontal=print(f'congratulations player {mark}! you have won by lining up horizontally on the board!')
    diagonal= print(f'congratulations player {mark}! you have won by lining up diagonally!')

    if board[1]==mark and board[2]==mark and board[3]==mark: 
        horizontal
    elif board[4]==mark and board[5]==mark and board[6]==mark:
         horizontal
    elif board[7]==mark and board[8]==mark and board[9]==mark:
        horizontal

    if board[1]==mark and board[4]==mark and board[7]==mark:
        vertical
    elif board[2]==mark and board[5]==mark and board[8]==mark:
            vertical
    elif board[3]==mark and board[6]==mark and board[9]==mark:
        vertical

    if board[1]==mark and board[5]==mark and board[9]==mark:
            diagonal
    elif board[3]==mark and board[5]==mark and board[7]==mark:
         diagonal
```

```
def game_rounds(round):
    player_moves=int(input('choose a number from 1 to 9: '))
    while True:
        if (player_moves)<1 or (player_moves)>9:
            print('unacceptable range')
        elif (player_moves)==1:
            real_board[1]='X'
        elif (player_moves)==2:
            real_board[2]='X'
        elif (player_moves)==3:
            real_board[3]='X'
        elif (player_moves)==4:
            real_board[4]='X'
        elif (player_moves)==5: 
            real_board[5]='X'
        elif (player_moves)==6:
            real_board[6]='X'           
        elif (player_moves)==7:
            real_board[7]='X'
        elif (player_moves)==8:
            real_board[8]='X'
        else:
            real_board[9]='X'
        break
    display_board(real_board)

def y_rounds(round):
    y_moves=int(input('choose a number from 1 to 9: '))

    while True:
        if (y_moves)<1 or (y_moves)>9:
            print('unacceptable range')
        elif (y_moves)==1:
            real_board[1]='O'
        elif (y_moves)==2:
            real_board[2]='O'
        elif (y_moves)==3:
            real_board[3]='O'
        elif (y_moves)==4:
            real_board[4]='O'
        elif (y_moves)==5: 
            real_board[5]='O'
        elif (y_moves)==6:
            real_board[6]='O'           
        elif (y_moves)==7:
            real_board[7]='O'
        elif (y_moves)==8:
            real_board[8]='O'
        else:
            real_board[9]='O'
        break
    display_board(real_board)
```

```
def run_game(full):
    game_on=True
    game_off=False
    t=0    
    while game_on:
            game_rounds(1)
            t+=1
            if t==5:
                break
            y_rounds(1)
            xchecker_tool(real_board, 'X')
            xchecker_tool(real_board, 'O')
```

```
run_game(1)
```

I am getting this output. From my understanding, the xchecker_tool function isn't defined properly which is why it prints the 'congrats' message every two turns even when 'x' or 'o' isn't lined up. I'd also like help in cleaning up the script as it's very long-winded but cannot do this at my current level because of recurrent errors.

```
choose a number from 1 to 9: 3
--------
|#|#|#|
--------
|#|#|#|
--------
|#|#|X|
--------
choose a number from 1 to 9: 5
--------
|#|#|#|
--------
|#|O|#|
--------
|#|#|X|
--------
congratulations player X! you have won by lining up vertically on the board!
congratulations player X! you have won by lining up horizontally on the board!
congratulations player X! you have won by lining up diagonally!
congratulations player O! you have won by lining up vertically on the board!
congratulations player O! you have won by lining up horizontally on the board!
congratulations player O! you have won by lining up diagonally!
```

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
vertical=print(f'congratulations player {mark}! you have won by lining up vertically on the board!')  
horizontal=print(f'congratulations player {mark}! you have won by lining up horizontally on the board!')
diagonal= print(f'congratulations player {mark}! you have won by lining up diagonally!')
```

`print` will be executed, and its return value will be bound to the variables. You define three variables - and thus `print` will be executed three times, outputting text to the terminal.

Code like this:

```
if board[1]==mark and board[2]==mark and board[3]==mark: 
        horizontal
```

Merely "mentions" the variable `horizontal`, which doesn't really execute anything. You could've as well written:

```
if board[1]==mark and board[2]==mark and board[3]==mark: 
    None  # won't do anything
    ...   # won't do anything either
    print
    board[1]
```

None of those will execute anything.

You should print in the `if` statements:

```
if board[1]==mark and board[2]==mark and board[3]==mark: 
    print(f'congratulations player {mark}! you have won by lining up horizontally on the board!')
# and so on for the other `if`s
```

Comment: thanks for the help! edited to say it's working correctly now!

Comment: This means none of the conditions in your `if` statements was `True`. That's a bug in the logic then

Comment: also, if the variables 'horizontal', 'vertical' etc were outside the function, would it execute as i intended?

Comment: No, you don't need these variables _at all_. "Mentioning" a variable like you're doing doesn't execute anything

Comment: I understand: I think i was confusing variables with functions that can simply be mentioned to execute.

Comment: @ElephontDearie, functions can't be "simply mentioned to execute" either - they have to be _called_: `print` isn't the same as `print()`. The first one by itself does nothing, the second one prints a new line.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you back off: don't try to write the entire program at once.  Your programming skills are not *yet* up to this level of complexity.  *I* don't write this much code at once.  Instead, write a block of code, debug it, and *then* go on.  Wherever you can, isolate the parts of code while you debug them.

For instance, hard-code a few test boards for your `xchecker_tool`; work on that until you can properly identify the winner/loser for each test-game situation.  You'll quickly see a problem: you don't presently understand how `print` works.

```
vertical=print(f'congratulations player {mark}! you have won by lining up vertically on the board!')
```

This statement prints a message and returns the value `None`, which you assign to `vertical`.  You do the same with two other variables.  You can easily discover this with a tracing statement:

```
print(vertical, horizontal, diagonal)
```

See this lovely [debug](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) blog for help.
Insert useful output statements to trace the control and data flow.

Your variables are merely value storage, *not* a way to pre-define a decision process.

---

See how this works?  When you hit a problem point, work through the applicable tutorial again.  Use that *immediately* to correct your most recent block of code.

Comment: ah i see now. If I had written `variable='blah blah'` and then `print(variable)` that would have been the right way

Comment: Perhaps -- *what* is this 'blah blah' that you're assigning to a variable?  Be careful with that.